# Python script copies the whole excel file instead of coping a single row

Tags: python

I am trying to remodule my copy of daily tracker. I have tried using this code to copy some portion  of a row:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('copy of 2020.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Half Hourly Tracker']

wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook('Example2.xlsx')
sheet1 = wb1['Sheet1'] 

ASIndex = 45

for i in range(1,5):
    sheet1.cell(row = 1, column = i).value = sheet.cell(row = 6, column = ASIndex).value
    ASIndex += 1

wb.save('copy of 2020.xlsx')
wb.save("example2.xlsx")
```

However, instead of copying a single row, the whole excel file is copied. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the last 2 lines your code is saving `wb` twice under both filenames and is not saving `wb1`. So even though your code is copying a part of the data, it isn't saving the copy.

Comment: wb.save("example2.xlsx") ---> wb1.save("example2.xlsx")